# Valuation of a Person's Life

Tags: united-states, civil-law, damages

When awarding damages in a wrongful death suit, what criteria are used to determine the "value" of the person's life?  Does the plaintiff and/or defendant have any input into this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Human life is worth between $1 million and $10 million. Apparently.

I did a quick Google search and found a couple of interesting sources to answer this question.

- [An academic study by Campbell Law](http://scholarship.law.campbell.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1078&context=clr)
- [A report from Cornell Law School](http://courses2.cit.cornell.edu/sociallaw/student_projects/victimcompensation.html)

In that second source, I found these interesting charts which seem to support the answer given.

[image]
[image]

[Also, this Wikipedia article says the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_of_life):

> #### Life Value in the US
>
> The following estimates have been applied to the value of life. The estimates are either for one year of additional life or for the statistical value of a single life.
>
> - $50,000 per year of quality life (international standard most private and government-run health insurance plans worldwide use to determine whether to cover a new medical procedure)
> - $129,000 per year of quality life (based on analysis of kidney dialysis procedures by Stefanos Zenios and colleagues at Stanford Graduate School of Business)
> - $9.1 million (Environmental Protection Agency, 2010)
> - $7.9 million (Food and Drug Administration, 2010)
> - $9.4 million (Transportation Department, 2015)
> - $9.1 million (Prof. W. Kip Viscusi, Vanderbilt University, 2013)